# Is there a way to use Firebase (Authentication) with Kotlin Multiplatform?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a project which uses Firebase Authentication in Android. It works well and I want to port the same project to an iOS App using code sharing with Kotlin Multiplatform.

I initially thought I could simple create a

```
expect class FirebaseAuth
```

and

```
//AndroidMain
actual class FirebaseAuth

//iOSMain
actual class FirebaseAuth
```

But I don't really know how I could use the iOS version of FirebaseAuth in iOSMain? Can someone guide me here?

Comment: to anyone researching on this I found this article here: https://medium.com/swlh/kotlin-multiplatform-ios-frameworks-dependencies-2320ca13ea30

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From now on there is a new official library about Kotlin Multiplatform firebase products. Supported platforms are Android, iOS and JavaScript.

https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/gitliveapp/firebase-kotlin-sdk/

Comment: is this officially supervised by the Firebase team?

Comment: It's not. It's just listed on the firebase site. That said, it's the best option currently.

Answer (score 7):

**Note:** This is an old answer. Check out https://github.com/gitliveapp/firebase-kotlin-sdk/ for a reasonably maintained library.

I gave a talk on libraries for KMP and specifically built a wrapper around Firestore to go along with it.

https://github.com/touchlab/FirestoreKMP

https://vimeo.com/371460823

In that library I create extension functions to implement features. Your question is kind of broad, but I'd probably start with:

```kotlin
//common
expect fun FirebaseAuth.signIn(email:String, password:String):Task<AuthDataResult>

//ios main
actual fun FirebaseAuth.signIn(email:String, password:String):Task<AuthDataResult> = signInWithEmail(email, password) //Figure out async return value
```

The async return stuff can be a little tricky, but the firestore code will have examples. One here:

https://github.com/touchlab/FirestoreKMP/blob/master/firestore/src/commonMain/kotlin/co/touchlab/firebase/firestore/Query.kt#L17

Comment: If I understood it correctly, I would need cinterop to make this work, right? I'm struggling on how to do it right and I'm really confuse about how to do it. I don't even know where to start (the very very basic of c interop) :(

Comment: I've been searching for hours and I feel so dumb that I don't understand a thing :( I don't fully understand how you properly setup your firestore (specially where you got all those firebase frameworks). :( Any tips on how I could start? I'm really sorry about this. :(

Comment: Hey, sorry I missed these. For those cinterop cofigs, I got the actual .framework files from a regular Xcode project and copied them over. However, if you're only using a few methods, you should just make interfaces and implement them with native code. Towards the end of that video above, that's what we do with Firebase Analytics rather than cinterop. Is really painful so I only use it when I really need to.

Comment: I am starting to under how it works now. I've been reading articles about Kotlin/Native trying to understand things more clearly. I think I'm still at the surface so I am thinking of actually getting my hands dirty and trying Kotlin/Native first with C and how they interop (I have a very limited C background and not know much of it and I feel like it is a big barrier in understanding Kotlin Multiplatform fully so I want to experience doing C with Kotlin/Native similar with how I learned Kotlin/JVM by doing it with Java). I dont know if its a good idea though.

Comment: The thing is I dont really understand things such as `compilerOpts`, `linkerOpts` that are present in `cinteropt`. I am hoping I'd understand it better (and why it is needed or what it is for) by getting my hands dirty (hopefully). I feel embarassed that I don't understand much of these things but also is quite excited on what I could possible discover. Hoping I could have that "Aha!" moment soon.

Comment: Also some update, I think I was able to make the whole thing work but the IDE (in this case Android Studio) could not see the actual types (they are all in red) so I'm kinda doubting myself whether I did it right.

Answer (score 3):

I am building and publishing Firebase Wrappers for Kotlin Multiplatform!

Keep in mind that only common API between JS, JVM and iOS are available.

Here it is: https://github.com/lamba92/firebase-multiplatform

Comment: looks like its in its very early stage? Will look into it, once stable this would be great.

Comment: Well, the Android wrapper works just fine, I am using them. The JS ones are a little buggy and I need help to test them. The iOS ones should work since ObjC is not a crappy language as JS and everything is statically typed so there should be almost no errors.